# PHP datafetch for loop bug

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting some weird data in my database (well it does not add up to what I'm trying to do)

Here's my for loop which counts from 1 to 52 in weeks and then makes a URL out if it to give to a function for processing

```
for ($week = 1; $week < 52 ; $week++) {
    kalenderFetch("heren2kalender","http://kovv.mavari.be/xlsKalenderScheidsrechter.aspx?&reeks=H3A&week=".$week);
}
```

The function to which it post then processes the URL and extracts the data from the table and inputs it to a database:

[image: data in table]

For as far al I can tell it does not input all data from all weeks, it just randomly stops sometimes I get more data sometimes less.

I was getting an awful lot of error (like time-exceptions and memory-exceptions)

Comment: Please add the code for `kalenderFetch` function.

Comment: Your loop also stops at week 51.

Comment: This is a problem with your HTML parsing. There's no good way to get this. You need to find an API or formatted data source.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/486c84939192289f9814

Comment: there is no api, nor am i allowed access to the database

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use:

```
for ($week = 1; $week <= 52 ; $week++)
```

Further, if you get time and memory exceptions, try:

```
set_time_limit(0);
memory_limit("128M");
```

Whether this works or not depends on your PHP settings. Maybe you also have to increase memory in your php.ini file.

Comment: i'v increades timelimit and memorylimit but now when i refesh the page chrome sais: page not found.
And the data in my db is still incomplete

Comment: That is because your browser has also a time limit. You could start the script from the console or save the week (session/cookie/database) and continue there with your next request.